How to execute non-ROS Python code in launch files?
I have an application where I'm happily using *.launch.py files BUT I would love to run non-ros (no node, no launch, etc) to populate some arguments of the downstream launch actions. Overall this seems to work over the surface, but when including this launch file in other launch files the non-ROS code gets executed multiple times.
One option would be to ROSify the Python code, but I would love not to do this. Another hack would be to ExcecuteProcess and try to run a Python script outside the current launch file, but this is rather impractical.
What I envision is extremely simple, and shouldn't require much effort (in my opinion) but I might be missing the right way to do this
Toy example
Let's say I have the following node that requires some information from the exterior world that will be used at runtime important_deterministic_parameter:
#!/usr/bin/python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node


class PrintParameterNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("print_parameter_node")
        self.declare_parameter("important_deterministic_parameter", -1.0)
        param_value = self.get_parameter("important_deterministic_parameter").value
        self.get_logger().info(f"Received deterministic parameter: {param_value}")


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = PrintParameterNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I have the following launch file that, it works fine when invoking it from the terminal $ ros2 launch ./application.launch.py. Up to this point, everything works as expected and I greatly enjoy not having to implement such logic in XML
import os
import time

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node


class ComplexClass:
    """ Please don't tell me to wrap this into a ROS node, because it does not rely on/need ROS at all,
    I just need to execute this Python code only once, as a normal Python script would do."""

    def __init__(self):
        # using the current time as an example only, don't take it seriously
        self.magic_number = time.time()
        print(
            f"Initializing my crazy custom logic with {self.magic_number}. This should be printed once"
        )

    def get_meaning_of_life(self) -> float:
        """A very python crazy logic going on here"""
        time.sleep(1)  # simulate the computation time with a delay
        # ...
        return self.magic_number


def generate_launch_description():
    # This is the block that is causing ros2 launch troubles----------
    life_parser = ComplexClass()
    life_meaning = life_parser.get_meaning_of_life()
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------

    # This is normal launch code
    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            Node(
                package=None,
                executable=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "simple_node.py"),
                parameters=[
                    {"important_deterministic_parameter": life_meaning},
                ],
                output="screen",
            )
        ]
    )

Here is the problem
Let's assume now my whole system got bigger and I want to call this application.launch.py from another launch file, that is also invoking other launch files as well:
import os

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource


# this is an upper level launch file. It doesn't need to know what is happening inside of the
# application.launch.py as it also launches many other applications
def generate_launch_description():

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.getcwd() + "/application.launch.py")
            )
        ]
    )

The issue is that when running that $ ros2 launch ./main.launch.py the custom Python code gets executed twice, but in practice, it gets invoked and runs as many layers of indirections you have in your launch system: if I now call main.launch.py from a 3rd launch file, then the custom code will get executed 3 times.
Besides being inconvenient, this delays the whole execution of the system, as they are all blocking calls. Additionally, the custom code will run n times, making the output of it non-deterministic or/and even repetitive ( assume that code writes to a certain new file, then you will get n files)
Output of the example

Main questions
Is there any way to work with the ROS python launch system in this way, without having to modify everything? I understand that in this case, I can wrap the custom class into a node, spit a topic, or anything similar, and so on. But I really would like to keep that logic ROS-independent
EDIT: Trying with OpaqueFunction
As @Nyquist suggested, I would attempt to solve this problem by wrapping the logic into an OpaqueFunction action
Although I'm still not convinced by the solution I came up with. It does help with the underlying situation of running the same Python code multiple times, which is s great improvement. But the solution has 2 problems 1) It's very intrusive, If I decide to go this way, then I would need to refactor a lot of launch files. 2) It still feels like overcomplicating the world. I understand that how the launch system is designed, it is tricky to do the thing I want to do. But honestly having to struggle so much to run the simplest Python code, it feels a bit absurd. Or maybe I'm getting something wrong, and the current launch system is no more powerful than the old XML, because it does not support running native Python code outside the actions context
class ComplexClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.magic_number = time.time()
        print(f"{self.magic_number}. This should be printed once")

    def get_meaning_of_life(self) -> float:
        time.sleep(1)
        return self.magic_number


def _generate_launch_description(context: LaunchContext, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = ComplexClass()
    obj.get_meaning_of_life()
    return [
        Node(
            package=None,
            executable=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "simple_node.py"),
            parameters=[
                {"important_deterministic_parameter": obj.get_meaning_of_life()},
            ],
            output="screen",
        ),
    ]


def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([OpaqueFunction(function=_generate_launch_description)])

Related topics and questions:

The most relevant for this question is Why "generate_launch_description" is called two times when I start a launch file from another launch file, as the main problem is that the custom python code is being called multiple times
https://discourse.ros.org/t/sequentially-starting-launch-files-using-ros-2-python-when-a-specific-log-message-is-detected/30633


I assume you consider execute process to be impractical because of your second link, not being able to "schedule" their execution? Have you already looked into the use of OpaqueFunction? It's a launch action on its own, so it should only execute once. It allows you to run all python functionality you want, but you can return launch configurations in this function.

Thanks for pointing this out. I edited the original post to also provide an example using this, which indeed works! so thanks a lot for the suggestion. I'm still not convinced by the solution, but I'm starting to feel there is no solution.
Regarding the ExecuteProcess I said is impractical because the ComplexClass is a python class, as was never intended to be invoked from the command line, which will involve turning the whole thing into an executable script, put it in the package, install it in the share directory and such...

yeah same, I think the launch system is not fully refined yet. But, considering it is replacing an XML system from ros1 I am pretty happy about all the convinces it comes with. Anyhow, glad this solution is at least for working for you!

Yes, 100% agree that is better than XML. Actually, I found this pattern: If you replace all your generate_launch_description with a user-defined _generate_launch_description and replace all the add_actions to plain Python list's append you can fix this problem in your whole launch system without changing more than that. Ugly, but works!
